# Why did the output repeate again in some substring?

Tags: c++, string

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    int main()
    {
        std::string s = "abcdefg";
        int n = s.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n;  i++)
        {
            for (int j = n; j > i; j--)
            {
                std::cout << s.substr(i,j) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to output substring from `abcdefg, abcdef,... a,` then, `bcdefg, bcdef...b,`.

However, the result shows it is repeated in some part, for example, `cdefg` repeated three times in my result, why and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is supposed to be *count*, i.e. the length of the substring, so change

```
std::cout << s.substr(i,j) << std::endl;
```

to

```
std::cout << s.substr(i,(j-i)) << std::endl;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1YOOl9vq9Hj4CXQ5)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because `j` is always being set to `n`.  You are telling `substr` to give you `n` counts past `i` which is not what you want.  You want from `i` to the end of the string and then decrease from there.

Change from `for (int j = n; j > i; j--)`

to `for (int j = (n - i); j > 0; j--)`